# Change X-axis Range in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, time, charts, oracle-apex, x-axis

How do I change the axis range in an oracle APEX graph chart. I would like to zone in on the data to to todays current day and the previous day. It is currently displaying two months worth of data. Is there a way I can do this using JavaScript. I currently have the x-axis as a time range and the y-axis is a temperature range between 0-100.[click to view current Chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tlMf.jpg)

Comment: Chart is based on SELECT statement; is it not? It says which values are to be used on X and Y axis so - wouldn't then modifying the SELECT statement itself (I presume by adding or modifying its WHERE clause) do what you want?

Comment: Hey Littlefoot, Oddly enough the graph is giving me an x-axis range of two months but the SELECT data only lives within a span of 3 days. I'm not sure what is causing that issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.